# Is it possible to do partial fraction expansion with specific degree of the variable?

Tags: functions

For example, here is a rational polynomial:
$$\frac{8 z^2}{8 z^2-6 z+1}$$

If I using Apart directly, the result is:
$$-\frac{1}{4 z-1}+\frac{2}{2 z-1}+1$$
but if I want to using $z^{-1}$ as the variable, the partial fraction expansion should be:
$$\frac{-1}{1-\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}}+\frac{2}{1-\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}}$$
Is this possible in Mathematica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
Apart[(8 z^2)/(8 z^2 - 6 z + 1) /. z -> 1/zi, zi] /. zi -> 1/z
(*4/(-4 + 1/z) - 4/(-2 + 1/z)*)
```

Comment: It works, thanks!

Comment: @FillLost You're welcome!